# Unable to receive structure array of dll in other dll through reflection C#

Tags: c#, dll, reflection

I tried to call a function in another dll through reflection which returns an array of structs. But at runtime this error occurs "Unable to convert first_dll.class1.mysturct[,] to second_dll.class1.mysturct[,]"

First dll:

```
/************  Ist dll ****************/
namespace first_dll
{
    class class1
    {
        public struct mystruct 
        {
            int a;
            byte b;
        };

        public static mystruct[,] function1(mystruct[,] parameter)
        {
            //manupluating structure array here and returning it
            return parameter;   
        }    
    }    
}
```

Second dll:

```
/******** Second dll *********/
namespace second_dll
{
    class class1
    {
        Methodinfo m; // global variable

        public struct mystruct
        {
            int a;    
            byte b;
        };

        public static void load_dll()
        {
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(@"path of first_dll");    
            Type type = assembly.Gettype("first_dll.class1");
            m = type.Getmethod("function1");
        }

        public void function2()
        {
            mystruct[,] structure = new mystruct[10,10];

            //adding value to structure here
            mystruct[,] structure_returning;  // declaring structure to store retuning array;
            //error occur here
            structure_returning = m.Invoke(null,new object[] { structure } )   

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You've got two identical types defined in different places under the same name. The compiler thinks they're different types. But if they really are identical, a cast should work.

Comment: their is also a error on calling function "Object of type first_dll.class1+mystruct[,]' cannot be converted to type 'second_dll.class1+mystruct[,]'."

Answer (score 0):

Just because two types are declared the same way they are not the same. This is called [duck typing](http://ericlippert.com/2014/01/02/what-is-duck-typing/), btw., and is only supported in a limited way in C#.

In order to solve this problem you need a third assembly (i.e. a third project in form of a class library) used to define contracts.  The contracts consist in definition of types commonly used in the two other assemblies. You can declare interfaces, classes (possibly abstract base classes), structs and so on.

Then reference this contracts assembly in the two other assemblies and use the types declared there.

The `string` type, for instance is identified by the following internal name (the so called assmebly qualified named):

> System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

As you can see, the assembly name "mscorlib" is included.